# Paypal e-mail verification

Tags: asp.net, paypal, verification

I want to add PayPal verified mail confirmation to our registration page. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the easiest way to do it would be use the IPN. Once they pay, the IPN page is automatically called. You can add any script to that page including a mailer script.

Comment: How do I send an e-mail address as a parameter for "VERIFIED" or "INVALID"

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Send email address? I thought you wanted to send email.  if ($status=="VERIFIED") {mail($to,$header,$....)}

Comment: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_ASP_NET_C.txt 
How can I paypal verified mail confirmation